# Excel color fill

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large spreadsheet with 50 or 60 rows of brightly colored red fill that I would like to change to a pale color. Other than S&Rreplace, is there a way to change all these rows' color at once. It would be a single color change to multiple rows.
Thanks.

Comment: Select them and change the fill colour?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a problem because all the rows aren't right next to each other. Have you tried filtering by color?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AODE.png

You should be able to highlight all the colored rows and recolor them this way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only 50-60, I would personally just use ctrl + LMB (cmd + LMB for MacOS) to select all the rows manually and then use the toolbar to change the color.

Not flashy or creative, but it gets the job done with about 1/3rd the necessary clicks.